# C++ Read Access Violotion 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, class, parsing, pointers

I am creating a program for a class where I need to use an array of pointers. When the program is compiled and begins to run, I then receive a error message saying:

```
 "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. this was 0xCDCDCDCD."
```

Is anyone able to look at the code below and help point me toward the issue? I've gone through it many times and cannot figure it out (I'm using Visual Studio 2019). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include "roster.h"
#include "student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include "degree.h"
#include <array>



//add array of pointers (classRosterArray) to hold data in studentDataTable
//Create student object for each student and populate classRosterArray
    //parse each set of data IDed in studentDataTable
    //add each student object to classRosterArray

Roster::Roster()
{
    this->capacity = 0;
    this->lastIndex = -1;
    this->classRosterArray = nullptr;
}

Roster::Roster(int capacity)
{
    this->capacity = capacity;
    this->lastIndex = -1;
    this->classRosterArray = new Student * [capacity];
}

void Roster::parseAdd(string row)
{
    if (lastIndex < capacity) {
        lastIndex++;
        int parray[Student::daysToCompleteSize];

        if (row[0] == 'S') {
            this->classRosterArray[lastIndex] = new Student();
            classRosterArray[lastIndex]->setDegree(SECURITY);
        }
        else if (row[0] == 'N') {
            this->classRosterArray[lastIndex] = new Student();
            classRosterArray[lastIndex]->setDegree(NETWORKING);
        }
        else if (row[0] == 'S') {
            this->classRosterArray[lastIndex] = new Student();
            classRosterArray[lastIndex]->setDegree(SOFTWARE);
        }
        else if (row[0] == 'U') {
            this->classRosterArray[lastIndex] = new Student();
            classRosterArray[lastIndex]->setDegree(UNDECIDED);
        }
        

        //ID
        int rhs = studentData[lastIndex].find(",");
        classRosterArray[lastIndex]->setStudentID(studentData[lastIndex].substr(0, rhs));

        //First Name
        int lhs = rhs + 1;
        rhs = studentData[lastIndex].find(",", lhs);
        classRosterArray[lastIndex]->setFirstName(studentData[lastIndex].substr(lhs, rhs - lhs));


        //Email Address
        lhs = rhs + 1;
        rhs = studentData[lastIndex].find(",", lhs);
        classRosterArray[lastIndex]->setEmailAddress(studentData[lastIndex].substr(lhs, rhs - lhs));

        //Age
        lhs = rhs + 1;
        rhs = studentData[lastIndex].find(",", lhs);
        classRosterArray[lastIndex]->setAge(studentData[lastIndex].substr(lhs, rhs - lhs));

        //Days
        lhs = rhs + 1;
        rhs = studentData[lastIndex].find(",", lhs);
        parray[0] = stoi(studentData[lastIndex].substr(lhs, rhs - lhs));

        //Days to Complete
        lhs = rhs + 1;
        rhs = studentData[lastIndex].find(",", lhs);
        parray[1] = stoi(studentData[lastIndex].substr(lhs, rhs - lhs));

        //Days to Complete
        lhs = rhs + 1;
        rhs = studentData[lastIndex].find(",", lhs);
        parray[2] = stoi(studentData[lastIndex].substr(lhs, rhs - lhs));

        //Set all Days
        classRosterArray[lastIndex]->setDaysToComplete(parray);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error, list has exceeded capacity. Exiting.";
        exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: I know the row 0 for each isn't valid

Comment: Since `this` was a bad pointer (taken from uninitialized dynamically allocated memory), likely the problem originated outside this code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why are you are creating an array of `Student*` pointers instead of an array of `Student` objects? Also, in `parseAdd()`, the 3rd `if` (`else if (row[0] == 'S')`) will never be entered if the 1st `if` (`if (row[0] == 'S')`) is true. You have multiple `if`'s testing for the same condition. But more importantly, if `row[0]` is none of the chars checked, then `studentData[lastIndex]` will be invalid in the rest of the code. This code is a very bad way to manage an array in general, least of all an array of pointers.

Comment: Note: When you see a number like 0xCDCDCDCD that is too regular to be an accident or a number that spells out something in English, you've probably been given a message by the program to help you debug. Look it up in [a list of common debug values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values) and see if it helps you out.

Comment: 0xCD is the "uninitialized value" pattern in MSVC++.  0xDD is the "deleted memory" pattern.  In debug builds, new heap memory is initialized to the former and filled with the latter on delete.  There is an uninitialized pointer somewhere.  Run the code in a debugger and the exception will stop execution.  If the exeception is not in your code, look at a stack trace and look backward until you are back in your code.  Then determine why that line of code has an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: My assignment was create an array of Student pointers, I know its a little weird.